# Change IP address with Python

Tags: python, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, ip, spoofing

I'm trying to build a program which opens Chrome pages one by one.
I'm using Selenium library.

My idea is to have different IP every time I open a new page.

I read about proxies but I'm not able to manage them.
Can you help me?

This is my code:

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.options = Options()
        self.options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
        self.options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver',options = self.options)

    def openBrowser(self):
        self.chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
    
    def closeBrowser(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #create object list
    object = [myClass(i) for i in range(10)]

    for i in range(10):
        #open Chrome page
        object[i].openBrowser()

        # here I want to change IP and then I close the page before opening a new one

        #close Chrome page
        object[i].closeBrowser()
```

Comment: that's not something you can directly do with python, unless you go the proxy route. Maybe a vpn with a cli that python could interact with?

Comment: @SuperStew Can you advice me one of these VPN?

Comment: protonvpn might work, but that might be only linux. you'll just have to google around

Comment: Take a look at TunnelBear VPN, it's a Chrome extension.